# Try block is ignored and catch block is showing the output everytime

Tags: javascript, jsp, oracle11g

Here is My question 
*Not checking the try block and directly moving to catch.
while running this code i have given required details and click on submit every time it shows the same output (ALREADY REGISTER WITH THIS CONTACT NO TRY AGAIN)

Expecting output:  THANK Q FOR U R REGISTRATION

*Try block is ignored

```
    <html><body bgcolor="PINK">
    <H3 ALIGN="RIGHT"><a href="main.jsp">LOGOUT</a></H3>
        </body>
    </html>



    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>



    <% try{
    String vcname=request.getParameter("cname");
    String vaddr=request.getParameter("addr");
    String vQualification=request.getParameter("Qualification");
    String vOccupation=request.getParameter("Occupation");
    String vCompany=request.getParameter("Company");
    String vaddr1=request.getParameter("addr1");
    String vContactno=request.getParameter("Contactno");
    int vContactno1=Integer.parseInt(vContactno);
    String vSalary=request.getParameter("Salary");
    String vDesignation=request.getParameter("Designation");
    String vsex=request.getParameter("sex");
    String vstate=request.getParameter("state");
    String vemail=request.getParameter("email");
    String vbank=request.getParameter("bank");

    String vasignto="null";
    //String vsanctioneddate="";
    %>


<%

//Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
//Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","scott","tiger");
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:soe","soe","soe");
Statement stmt=con1.createStatement();
String vsql1="select sysdate from admin";
ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery(vsql1);
rs1.next();

java.sql.Date d=rs1.getDate("SYSDATE");
//java.sql.Date d1=new Date(null);
java.sql.Date d1=null;
%>



<%
//Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
//Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","scott","tiger");
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:soe","soe","soe");

String vsql="insert into  customers values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(vsql);
pstmt.setString(1,vcname);
pstmt.setString(2,vaddr);
pstmt.setString(3,vQualification);
pstmt.setString(4,vOccupation);
pstmt.setString(5,vCompany);
pstmt.setString(6,vaddr1);

pstmt.setInt(7,vContactno1);
pstmt.setString(8,vSalary);
pstmt.setString(9,vDesignation);
pstmt.setString(10,vsex);
pstmt.setString(11,vstate);
pstmt.setString(12,vasignto);
pstmt.setString(13,vemail);
pstmt.setString(14,"NoB");
pstmt.setString(15,vbank);
pstmt.setDate(16,d);
pstmt.setDate(17,d1);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
out.print("<center> <font color=\"blue\"><BR><BR><B>THANK Q FOR U R REGISTRATION<br></font></CENTER>");
out.print("<center> <font color=\"blue\"><BR><BR><B><A HREF=\"loans.jsp\"><B>BACK</A><br></font></CENTER>");
//out.print("<td><a href=\"display.jsp\">DISPLAY</a></td></tr>");
}catch(Exception e){out.println("<center> <font color=\"blue\"><BR><BR><B>ALREADY REGISTED WITH THIS CONTACTNO TRY AGIN</font></CENTER>");
String vbank=request.getParameter("bank");%>

<center><a href="bdisp.jsp?bank=<%=vbank%>"><b>BACK</a></center>

<%
}
%>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the debug of the exception ?

Comment: Try block is not checking and directly moving to catch